# Run Function within iframe | NW.js (node-webkit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, nw.js

I'm attempting to call a function set in an iframe, from the parent document.  Here's what I mean..

INDEX.HTML

```
<script>
$('#iframe').contentWindow.showAssetPicker();
</script>
<iframe src="test.html" id="iframe">
```

TEST.HTML

```
<script>
function showAssetPicker(){
  alert('worked!');
  //Do a lot
}
</script>
```

That's what I've got right now.  As you can tell, the index should be calling a function defined within the iFrame - but it's not.  It's just telling me it's undefined.

Hopefully this makes sense to you.   Also, I am using NW.js (node-webkit) to make iFrames completely controlled.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Anybody?  I wish this would like, bump the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery-selector returns an array of selected DOM elements. In your case, you would pick the first (and probably only) element:

```
$('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.showAssetPicker();
```

Comment: Man, that works even better.  Thanks!  Could you check out this post of mine, since you are so wise in the ways of the iframe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061007/setting-javascript-context-to-iframe-in-an-iframe?noredirect=1#comment48237093_30061007

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching, I found my answer.
That will set the javascript context to the iframe, and then call the function.

```
window.frames['iframe'].showAssetPicker();
```