# Setting Javascript Context to iFrame in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, nw.js

I have a page with an `<iframe>`, and inside that `<iframe>` another `<iframe>` pops up as a window.   What I'm trying to do is call a function that is set in the `<iframe>`'s `<iframe>`....  I know, lot's of the same tag going on.

Here's what I mean in HTML format.

```
<body>
 <iframe src="blahblah.html" name="iframe">
  //blahblah.html html
  <iframe src="blahblahpopup.html" name="iFrame2">
   //blahblahpopup.html html, also where the function is set.
  </iframe>
 </iframe>
</body>
```

So, as you can see, there is an `<iframe>` in an `<iframe>`.

Now lets get down to business.  I'm using this JS code to get my JS context into the first level `<iframe>` with the name 'iframe'

```
window.frames['iframe'].showAssetPicker();
```

What that does is it calls the popup inside the first-level `<iframe>`.  But now I need to call a function inside of the popup that was just called.  (which is yet another `<iframe>`...  I'm not the cause of all the `<iframe>`'s...)

So here's my failed attempt of calling a function defined in the second-level `<iframe>`...

```
window.frames['iframe'].frames['iFrame2'].populateTypePullDown('/getdata/');
```

I also tried

```
window.frames['iframe'].window.frames['iFrame2'].populateTypePullDown('/getdata/');
```

Neither seem to work.  Any help with this?  I am using node-webkit to remove `<iframe>` security restrictions.

Thanks for any help you can throw my way!

P.S. Goodness gracious, I said `<iframe>` far too many times in this post.

Comment: Have you tried using `window.frames['iframe'].contentWindow` instead?

Comment: Any error in the browser console?

Comment: It says the function is not defined.  Which means I'm not getting in the correct context..

Answer (score 3):

Probably the issue is that you don't wait before the Asset Picker is loaded and therefore the function `populateTypePullDown` is not yet defined.

Try something like this:

```
$('#iframe')
    .ready(function() {
        var $innerIframe = $(this).contents().find('#iFrame2');
        console.log($innerIframe, 'ready');
        $innerIframe.get(0).contentWindow.populateTypePullDown('/vsg/ipm/SecuredOfferRepository');
    })
    .get(0).contentWindow.showAssetPicker();
```

Comment: Sounds like a good answer, but I just figured it out using your answer from the other question. :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out yourself. :)

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you one last thing?  How could I run a script through the context of an iframe?  Like, instead of just calling a function.

Comment: You could inject a `script` tag and set the `src` attribute, if that is what you want. `$innerIframe.contents().find('body').append($('<script>').attr(src, 'js/myscript.js'));`

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer.  What I did was I reached inside the main `<iframe>`, and got the contentWindow of the `<iframe>` inside.

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('#iFrame').get(0).contentWindow.performSearch();
```